# How to apply a function for each of the various entries from different matrices as index?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bilinear-interpolation

I'm writing a function in matlab which mimics the built-in 'imwarp' function (applying geometric transformation) without using any kind of loops. i'm in the final step when i have to call my function for bi-linear interpolation for every index in final 2D image.

I have 3 arrays here , 'pts' have homogenized vectors (x,y,1) for which i interpolate and 'row' and 'cols' have x and y coordinates respectively for resultant image where interpolated intensity value would be placed.

```
finalImage (rows(1,:),cols(1,:))=bilinear(pts(:,:),im);
```

Kindly correct my syntax here to do it properly. thanks in advance.

Comment: The bilinear transform is a method for converting from analog to digital representation (Laplace to z-transform). I would guess that you want to use `interp2`

Comment: i'd appriciate an example of that according to my context.

Comment: and here bilinear interpolation is being used for hole-filling in transformed image.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple implementation of applying an affine transformation to an image. Some of the matrices may be reversed because I did this from memory. I don't know exactly how you are formatting your pts array so I figure a working example is the best I can do. The `interp2` function applies bilinear interpolation, the `bilinear` function performs the bilinear transform which describes analog filters as digital filters. This is not what you want.

P.S. You have to make sure to use the inverse transform when applying image warping (that is, define the point you want to sample in the input image for each point in the output image). If you perform the forward transform (i.e. define the point in the output image that each point in the input image maps to) then you will end up with some serious aliasing effects and potentially holes in the output image.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have questions.

```
img = double(imread('rice.png'))/255;

theta = 30; % rotate 30 degrees
R  = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0; ...
      sind(theta)  cosd(theta) 0; ...
      0          0          1];

sx = 15; % skew by 15 degrees in x
Skx = [1 tand(sx) 0; ...
       0 1  0; ...
       0 0  1];

% Translate by 1/2 size of image
tx = -size(img, 2)/2;
ty = -size(img, 1)/2;
T = [1 0 tx; ...
     0 1 ty; ...
     0 0 1];

% Scale image down by 1/2
sx = 0.5;
sy = 0.5;
S = [sx 0  0; ...
     0  sy 0; ...
     0  0  1];

% translate, scale, rotate, skew, then translate back
A = inv(T)*Skx*R*S*T;

% create meshgrid points
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:size(img,2), 1:size(img,1));

% reshape so we can apply matrix op
V = [reshape(x, 1, []); reshape(y, 1, []); ones(1, numel(x))];

Vq = inv(A)*V;

% probably not necessary for these transformations but project back to the z=1 plane
Vq(1,:) = Vq(1,:) ./ V(3,:);
Vq(2,:) = Vq(2,:) ./ V(3,:);

% reshape back into a meshgrid
xq = reshape(Vq(1,:), size(img));
yq = reshape(Vq(2,:), size(img));

% use interp2 to perform bilinear interpolation
imgnew = interp2(x, y, img, xq, yq);

% show the resulting image
imshow(imgnew);
```

Comment: error : To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
on : xq = reshape(Vq(1,:), size(img));

Comment: I made this specifically for a grayscale image, If you have a color image then it won't work. If you use 'rice.png' (built into MATLAB) then that should work (i.e. if you copy-paste this code as is into MATLAB you should get a result). If you are doing 3 channel images then you can separate the image into 3 images (red, green, blue) and operate on each one independently.